# Un-clear intervals?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make it so that function Rotate can be called more than once?
Because of me clearing the interval, it only works once

```
var Rotation = 0;

        function Rotate() {
                var x = setInterval(function() {
                    if (Rotation < 61) {
                        Rotation = Rotation + 1;
                        document.getElementById("Test").style.transform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
                        document.getElementById("Test").style.msTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
                        document.getElementById("Test").style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
                        console.log("Rotated "+Rotation+" degrees.")
                    }
                    else {
                        clearInterval(x);
                        var y = setInterval(function() {
                            if (Rotation > 0) {
                                Rotation = Rotation - 1;
                                document.getElementById("Test").style.transform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
                                document.getElementById("Test").style.msTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
                                document.getElementById("Test").style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";  
                                console.log("Rotated "+Rotation+" degrees.")
                            }
                        }, 1)

                    }                       
                }, 1)
        }
```

Comment: Then don't clear the interval.

Comment: That would be the best way to do it, in a single interval without clearing it. However I believe he might have a need to implement it that way. He didnt specified it in the question.

Comment: Can't you just reset the value of the global *Rotation*, then call it again? Or do you mean you want to call it multiple times and have a few running at once? Also, variables starting with a captial letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors. It's a bit confusing when they are used for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Add an else statement for this if:

```
if (Rotation > 0)
```

with this content:

```
clearInterval(y);
Rotate();
```

Comment: Sorry but I am confused

Comment: According to your code, the interval stops doing anything after the Rotation variable reaches 0 in the "y" interval. You need to clear that interval and start the Rotate again if that happens, adding the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this

```
var Rotation = 0;
var RotateDirection = 1;
function Rotate() {
    setInterval(function(){
    Rotation = Rotation + RotateDirection;
    document.getElementById("Test").style.transform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
    document.getElementById("Test").style.msTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
    document.getElementById("Test").style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+Rotation+"deg)";
    if( Rotation == 60 || Rotation == 0 ) RotateDirection *= -1;
    console.log("Rotated "+Rotation+" degrees.");}, 1);
}
```

You don't need to use `clearInterval`, you don't need two functions. The above function will rotate 0 to 60 and 60 to 0, again and again.

Comment: That doesn't stop rotating though, it simply repeats over and over again, increasing speed each time